# how to browse multiple files and select any of them through dropdown in R?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I was trying to browse multiple files and show the list of uploaded files in dropdown box but on selecting any option I am not able to generate its data. I know this is because I am not reading csvs and I don't know how to link that file with its data. Please guide me on this.

```
data_sets <- c("mtcars", "morley", "rock")
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            h2("Dashboard tab content"),
            sidebarPanel(
              fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File",multiple = TRUE,
                        accept = c(
                          "text/csv",
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                          ".csv")


  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    data_sets<-rbind(data_sets,c(input$file[1]))
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
}
```

)